# SQL Server column datatype and indexable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016

I need to store variable string length in a SQL Server table, length can vary 0 to 10000 or so characters.

I need to filter the text with like operator `%abc` or `abc%`.

I thought of using `varchar` or `nvarchar`, but I'm unable to create index on this datatype.

Please suggest design advise for choosing the column data type and make the column indexable.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server will use an index for `like 'abc%'`.  However, it will not use the index if the wildcard is first.

If you are searching for complete words, then you should investigate [`contains()` and full text search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql).

Comment: Thank you Gordan.  Requirement is not to search for complete text but for the ending text '%abc', Is there any function like endswith.

Comment: @sri . . . Just use the wildcards . . . `like '%abc'`.

Answer (score 3):

> *I thought of using varchar or nvarchar, but I'm unable to create index on this datatype.*

Those **are** the proper datatypes for text based information.

The reason you're not able to create an index has nothing to do with the **datatype** per se - but in SQL Server, an index can be created only if the column (or set of columns) in the index have a max. theoretical size of **900 bytes** (or less).

This means, a `VARCHAR(1000)` (or `VARCHAR(MAX)`) **cannot** be indexed. This size limit is your issue - not the datatype.

Solution: there's really only one solution: use fewer bytes in the columns you want to index. Or alternatively, as Gordon suggested, check out the full-text indexing capabilities of SQL Server.